# Possible Combination of Metric Tensors

Tags: metric-tensor

I'm trying to compute a Lagrangian involving derivative self-interactions of a vector field ($\partial_{a}A_{b}$) coupled with a scalar field ($\partial_{ab}\phi$). When doing that I need to evaluate the possible contractions of eight metric tensors, and the block components of derivatives. The question is: How many possible independent permutations of indices are allowed to the term:

$$g^{ab}g^{cd}g^{ef}g^{ij}g^{kl}g^{mn}g^{op}g^{rs}$$

There is any kind of recursion formula for that?. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have 2 *n* indices to distribute to *n* metrics; in your example *n*=8.

You might visualize the counting in the *n*=2 case, *abcd*. P(2)=3, as *a* may be paired with *b,c*, or *d*. So you distribute 2 *n* indices into a sequence of 2 *n* boxes, (2 *n*)! perms; and then clump each box doublet to a symmetric metric, so divide by $2^n$, and divide by the inconsequential perms of the boxes/metrics, so *n*!. Consequently, 
$$
P(n)= \frac{(2n)!}{n! ~ 2^n}~~, 
$$
checking with the toy example above. (See this [figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial).)

For your explicit example,
$$
P(8)= \frac{(16)!}{8! ~ 2^8}= 2027025~. 
$$

Comment: aka, $P(n)=(2n-1)!!$, which is the number of pairings (Wick contractions).